# Does old facebook page feed still work?

Tags: facebook

Can we still access information using the old facebook page feed?

I have a client that still gets an rss feed from:
http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=atom10&id=...

Will this feed work for all public facebook webpages? and if so how long?

How come it isn't documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not document because the rss feeds are not meant to work like this. The right way to access "Public" posts of a page is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed
```

You may also use FQL.